# How to modify argument list in a function?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm writing a code that takes an argument list and permanently modifies it by slicing. The function should not return anything, but when I call the list in the console it should be edited.

```
def slice_in_place(a_list, start, end):
    a_list = a_list[start:end]
```

When I do something like:

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
slice_in_place(my_list, 1, 3)
```

The argument list is still the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should assign the sliced list to the list in-place:

```
def slice_in_place(a_list, start, end):
    a_list[:] = a_list[start:end]
```